# skipping a function parameter?

Tags: php, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I have this problem but I don't know how to name it, for instance, I have this function,

```
function test($param1,$param2 = false,$param3 = false)
{

    if($param2 == true)
    {
        return '2';
    }

    elseif($param3 == true)
    {
        return '3';
    }

    else 
    {
        return '1';
    }
}
```

In order to return '3', I have to evoke my function like this,

```
$test = test('test',false,true);
```

I want to ask whether I can skip the second param and return '3' by evoking the function like this?

```
$test = test('test',$param3 = true);
```

Or any other method to do so?

Comment: With PHP 8.x you can use [named parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) to skip arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fake named parameters, as seen here on SO:

[Emulating named function parameters in PHP, good or bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680368/emulating-named-function-parameters-in-php-good-or-bad-idea)

Here is a sample of the correct answer you should be looking for on this page:

```
function myFunc (array $args) {
    $default = array(
        "name" => "John Doe",
        "age" => "30"
    );
    // overwrite all the defaults with the arguments
    $args = array_merge($defaults, $args);
    // you *could* extract($args) here if you want

    echo "Name: " . $args['name'] . ", Age: " . $args['age'];
}

myFunc(array("age" => 25)); // "Name: John Doe, Age: 25"
```

Comment: thanks. I think it should not be a 's' at `$defaults`. The line should be - `$args = array_merge($default, $args);`

Comment: With PHP 8.x you can use [named parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) to skip arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the parameters in an array:

```
$params = array(
    'param1' => 'test',
    'param3' => true
);

$result = myFunction($params);

function myFunction($params) {
    if (isset($params['param3']) && $params['param3']) {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for your paramaters like this:

```
function someFunction( $varA, $varB=false, $varC=false)
{
    if($varB==true)
    {
      return 'b';
    }
}
```

When you call the function, you can do `someFunction(true)`, `someFunction(true, true)`, or `someFunction(true, true, true)`.  The only catch is you can't declare A and C without also declaring B.

Edit:
Missed first line.  You could also pass your variables as an array.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. If you want to pass $param3 to the function, you will have to pass all the parameters preceding $param3 in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask whether I can skip the second param and return '3' by evoking the function like this?

No, you cannot. The only way to "skip" a parameter is by sending something like `NULL`. But then your function needs to look like:

```
function foo($a, $skip_me = NULL, $b = 1);
{
  if ($skip_me === NULL) $skip_me = false; // set the default value like this
}

foo(1, NULL, 2);
```

The other option is to send an array and have the function take a single parameter. That can be useful if you have a lot of optional arguments.