# Optional parameters aren't truly optional

Tags: php

I would like to have *real* optional parameters in PHP. I realize that I can do something like this:

```
function my_function($req_var, $opt_var1 = 90, $opt_var2 = "lala") {
    die("WEEEEEEEE!");
}
```

However, if I want to only specify the value of `$opt_var2`, I still must specify a value for `$opt_var1`.

Here's an example.

```
my_function("lala", 90, "omg");
```

In other words, I have to explicitly write `90` as `$opt_var1` even though it's only `$opt_var2` that I want to change.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
my_function("lala", default, "omg");
```

That would be so helpful.

Comment: Define your **optional** parameters after your **required** parameters

Comment: That's not the solution. Notice that I have 2 optional parameters, and I only wish to change the last one.

Comment: You may use an array of parameters. It's a workaround, though.

Comment: Definitely check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680368/emulating-named-function-parameters-in-php-good-or-bad-idea it emulates the `Python` kwargs behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way with array parameters:

```
function my_func(array $params = array()){
    $arg1 = isset($params['one']) ? $params['one'] : 'default';
    $arg2 = isset($params['two']) ? $params['two'] : 'default';
    $arg3 = isset($params['three']) ? $params['three'] : 'default';

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function my_function($req_var, $opt_var1 = NULL, $opt_var2 = NULL) {
    if ($opt_var1 === NULL) {
        $opt_var1 = 90;
    }
    if ($opt_var2 === NULL) {
        $opt_var2 = "lala"
    }
}
my_function("lala", NULL, "omg");
```

Comment: And what if `NULL` might also be a valid value that I wish to be able to parse into the function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a parameter that is an associative array and `extract` it:

```
function func($options= array()) {
    $option1= "default value";
    ..
    extract($options);
    ..
}
```